# SSIS 2008 working with ADO.NET destination

Tags: ado.net, ssis

I am trying to load data from falt file source to Sybase IQ 15.1 destination using SSIS 2008. I am using ADO.NET destination component with Sybase IQ ODBC data provider to connect to the Sybase IQ db. Though the package is able to load the data, performance of the package is extremely slow. Its just loading 150 rows per minute. I am executing the package through SQL Server Agent. There are no data transformations in the package. 
Can any one please tell me how can i improve the performance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ODBC drivers are generally slow. How many columns are you pulling in? Also, have you checked your buffer sizes and stuff?

Comment: I got solution, i used Sybase SQL Anywhere OLDB Provider 11 and destination also OLDB Provider. http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1085077&id=1085077

Answer (score 0):

Use **BulkInsertWheneverPossible** property to true, it will improve the performance.
To access that property right click->ADO.NET destination-> choose properties or ShowAdvanceEditor

(MSDN Reference)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135971(v=sql.105).aspx#adonet

A value that specifies whether to use the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy interface to improve the performance of bulk insert operations. Only certain ADO.NET providers support this interface.

The default value is True.